# Real binary write PHP

Tags: php, binary

How do I do something as simple as (in PHP) this code in C:

```
char buffer[5] = "testing";
FILE* file2 = fopen("data2.bin", "wb");
fwrite(buffer, sizeof buffer, 1, file2);
fclose(file2);
```

Whenever I try to write a binary file in PHP, it doesn't write in real binary.

Example:

```
$ptr = fopen("data2.bin", 'wb');

fwrite($ptr, "testing");

fclose($ptr);
```

I found on internet that I need to use `pack()` to do this...

What I expected:

```
testing\9C\00\00
or
7465 7374 696e 679c 0100 00
```

What I got:

```
testing412
```

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think it's not writing in "real binary"? What does that mean?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't write in real binary" ? What were you expecting the result to be, and what did you get?

Comment: I'm expecting to get something like 4d61 7572 6963 696f 0063 ecbf 855a 61b7 00d6 7bb7 1200 0000 00ba 7f47 but I only get plaintext like a regular text file.

Comment: OBS: that was read by a hex editor

Comment: Whether a file is binary or text is just an interpretation by the program using it. Everything is binary internally, that's all that computers know about.

Comment: Updated... maybe it help.

Comment: Note that neither of your example code matches your output! Please don't show the code from one thing, and the output from another... it is *ridiculously* confusing (to you and us!)

Comment: same as my question, same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62144562/crazy-php-fopen-fwrite-file-put-contents-bug-with-binary-mode-writing-nothin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making the classic mistake of confusing *data* with the *representation* of that data.

Let's say you have a text file. If you open it in Notepad, you'll see the following:

```
hello
world
```

This is because Notepad **assumes** the data is [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) text. So it takes every byte of raw data, interprets it as an ASCII character, and renders that text to your screen.

Now if you go and open that file with a hex editor, you'll see something entirely different<sup>1</sup>:

```
68 65 6c 6c 6f 0d 0a 77 6f 72 6c 64          hello..world
```

That is because the hex editor instead takes every byte of the raw data, and displays it as a two-character hexadecimal number.

<sub>1 - Assuming Windows `\r\n` line endings and ASCII encoding.</sub>

---

So if you're expecting hexadecimal ASCII output, you need to *convert* your string to its hexadecimal encoding before writing it (as ASCII text!) to the file.

In PHP, what you're looking for is the [`bin2hex`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) function which "Returns an ASCII string containing the hexadecimal representation of str."  For example:

```
$str = "Hello world!";
echo bin2hex($str);      // output:  48656c6c6f20776f726c6421
```

---

Note that the `"wb"` mode argument doesn't cause any special behavior. It guarantees ***binary*** output, not ***hexadecimal*** output. I cannot stress enough that there is a difference. The only thing the `b` really does, is guarantee that line endings will not be converted by the library when reading/writing data.

Comment: Thanks! But why PHP doesn't do that already? In C, if I put "wb" as argument on fopen, it saves everything in binary... But in PHP it seems that it is just ignored.

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano No, C absolutely does not do what you just described.  Please compile and run your C code from the question, and open the result in a *text editor*. You'll see ASCII.  The `"wb"` mode does **not** do what you think it does.

Comment: But it doesn't save in ASCII, because if I open with Notepad, it shows strange characters...

Comment: Sample:

 char buffer[7] = "testing";
 int number = 412;

 FILE* file2 = fopen("data2", "wb");
 fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file2);
 fwrite(&number, 1, sizeof(number), file2);

 fclose(file2);

Comment: Right, you're writing an **integer** `412` to the file. So if you look at just that part in a hex editor, you're going to see `9c 01 00 00`, which is a 4-byte little-endian integer shown as four 1-byte hexadecimal numbers.  If you wrote the **string** `"`char str[] = "412"`, you would see something totally different.

Comment: You should really play around with this stuff until it makes *perfect sense*, as it is very fundamental to how computers and binary data work.