# Crazy PHP fopen / fwrite / file_put_contents / move_uploaded_file bug with binary mode writing on CentOS Linux Adding 0x0D to every 0x0A

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, line-endings, file-put-contents

Seems the file keeps adding 0x0D to my saved binary files no matter what setting I put in the `fopen` `mode` flag.

It's not only affecting `fopen`/`fwrite`.. but also `file_put_contents`.

`file_get_contents` I thought was the problem to begin with.. but it turns out this one is actually working okay.. because when I dumped the file using bin2hex() it came out good.

I was blaming at first the `std::string` in C++ for this bug.. but it turns out it doesn't even have anything to do with C++ but it's in fact a bug with PHP or maybe with only CentOS linux and I have yet to find a solution to store my file in binary.. best I could do is hexstring dump file which works..

Look at my code and screenshots.

```
$target_file = "/privatefiles/" . basename($_FILES["a"]["name"]);
$fileTypeExtension = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

//Check file extension.
if($fileTypeExtension != "dll" && $fileTypeExtension != "exe" ) die("ER");

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["a"]["size"] > 10*(1024*1024)) //10 MB cap
  die("ER");

//To decode a base64 encoded file (this was a quickfix to fix binary file encoding in C++ part).
$fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['a']['tmp_name']);
$fileContent = base64_decode($fileContent);

//fail
$fh = fopen("wtf1.bin", "wb");
fwrite($fh, $fileContent, strlen($fileContent));
fclose($fh);

//fail (exact result as top)
$fh = fopen("wtf2.bin", "wb");
$fileContent = bin2hex($fileContent);
for($i=0;$i<strlen($fileContent);$i+=2)
    fwrite($fh, chr(hexdec(substr($fileContent,$i,2))));
fclose($fh);

//good result.. but not binary
$fh = fopen("wtf3.bin", "w");
$fileContent = bin2hex(base64_decode(file_get_contents($_FILES['a']['tmp_name'])));
fwrite($fh, $fileContent);
fclose($fh);

//good result but not binary
file_put_contents($target_file, $fileContent); //good bin2hex.

//fail same as the top 2 fail's.
file_put_contents($target_file."_", file_get_contents($_FILES['a']['tmp_name'])); //bad same as wtf1.bin or wtf2.bin
```

Here are my screenshots (proof of what is happening from running the code above), and initiating a file upload using C++ application (which cannot be bugged because at first I sent using raw binary mode.. then after this 0x0D 0x0A bug I changed it to base64 encoding to fix the transfer problem.. and it turns out that wasn't even the problem, but in fact a PHP problem I believe..

Here is the original binary file (not altered) this is what I upload (as you can see I stop at 0x0A 0x40 to show you the bug).
[image: original]

Here is wtf1.bin (Just a simple 1 liner of base64_decode to file) at same offset.
[image: wtf1]

Here is wtf2.bin (Some hackery I tried to do to fix this problem using bin2hex which dumps it good) at same offset.
[image: wtf2]

Here is wtf3.bin (bin2hex) which works good at same offset. (0x846 / 2 = 0x423) (same offset confirmed!)
[image: wtf3]

[image: phpversion]

Even this simple upload script, uploads corrupted files with 0xA,0xD

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Upload your files</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="test.php" method="POST">
    <p>Upload your file</p>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"></input><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"></input>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
  if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
  {
    $path = basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    print_r($_FILES);
    $size = filesize($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);
    echo "<br>size uploaded = " . $size . "<br>";
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
      echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']). 
      " has been uploaded<br>";
      echo "path = " . $path . "<br>";
      echo "size stored = " . filesize($path);
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
  }
?>
```

Bug happens when I just upload these bytes in binary format

> BC 09 00 00 83 C4 04 BA E8 57 40 00 8D 64 24 00 8A 08 88 0A 40 42 84 C9

I get back on server

> BC 09 00 00 83 C4 04 BA E8 57 40 00 8D 64 24 00 8A 08 88 0D 0A 40 42 84 C9

Comment: Before anything else in your PHP form - can you check the size of `$_FILES['uploaded_file']` ? Both from `filesize()` and the `size` property inside `$_FILES`. If the size is the same as your local file - then the problem is **not** the web server.

Comment: So where/how exactly are you looking at the file contents, and see those extra carriage returns? Are you checking them _on_ the server - or are you downloading them back to the client first?

Comment: @CBroe I am downloading them using SSH FTP (SFTP) and viewing them in the same editor that shows me the original file in perfect hex pattern..,

Comment: @IVO GELOV https://i.imgur.com/ybqRtLb.png and https://i.imgur.com/5tXohiE.png you are right the filesize on drive seems good, but when I open in my editor it shows as 25 bytes instead of 24.. very strange... could it be my editor this whole time. original: https://i.imgur.com/n1vFmAm.png downloaded: https://i.imgur.com/5cmsz9R.png I think I figured my issue out it's not the editor but the SFTP Client (WinSCP) that has this problem.

Comment: Are you sure you did the re-download in FTP “binary” mode? (Many FTP clients have an “ASCII mode”, in which they will try to _translate_ line endings between different OS.)

Comment: Thanks CBroe and IVO GELOV that was it, and to think I struggled so much with this thinking it was my uploader or my PHP server,  I solved the problem, It was the force Text-Mode setting for all files it was turned on by default like you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks CBroe and IVO GELOV, The issue was in my FTP/SFTP Client WinSCP. I attached a screenshot which setting you need to turn off so this problem doesn't happen.

[image: Solved]